# Adding Fragments in HorizontalListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want horizontalListview with vertical scrolling. Earlier i tried to implement it using Horizontalscrollview inside Listview. It works fine for static no. of data items. But In my case they are dynamic.
So i downloaded a library(code) of **HorizontalListView** from [Here](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)

Now i made the HorizontalListViewDemo activity a fragment and called it in another activity. I aimed at calling it multiple times within activity with vertical scrollview.
But I tried with 1 Fragment and application crashes. LogCat shows error in Layoutinflator on HorizontalListViewDemo fragment.

**HorizontalListViewDemo**

```
public class HorizontalListViewDemo extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewdemo, container, false);
        HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return view;



    }

    /* @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.listviewdemo);

        HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }*/



    private static String[] dataObjects = new String[]{ "Text #1",
        "Text #2",
        "Text #3",
        "Text #4" }; 

    private BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {

        private OnClickListener mOnButtonClicked = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                /*
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HorizontalListViewDemo.this);
                builder.setMessage("hello from " + v);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Cool", null);
                builder.show();*/

            }
        };

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return dataObjects.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);
            TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
            Button button = (Button) retval.findViewById(R.id.clickbutton);
            button.setOnClickListener(mOnButtonClicked);
            title.setText(dataObjects[position]);

            return retval;
        }

    };

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Logcat**

```
06-15 01:34:37.139: D/AndroidRuntime(300): Shutting down VM
06-15 01:34:37.139: W/dalvikvm(300): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tryntry/com.example.tryntry.Struct}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class HorizontalListView
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class HorizontalListView
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at com.example.tryntry.HorizontalListViewDemo.onCreateView(HorizontalListViewDemo.java:22)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at com.example.tryntry.Struct.onCreate(Struct.java:13)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  ... 11 more
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.HorizontalListView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.tryntry-1.apk]
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
06-15 01:34:37.219: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  ... 30 more
06-15 01:34:39.449: I/Process(300): Sending signal. PID: 300 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you please post the stack trace from LogCat?

Comment: Please check again. I have included it above now.

Answer (score 0):

title.setText(dataObjects[position]); << i guess it should be a ' String '